# Next/image incredibly slow on first load

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I have got some text columns with an image on the side and thought I would be a good idea to use next/image. The image size wend from 640 kb to 183 kB so far so good. But after deployment the image takes seconds to appear. If I switch back to a normal img tag it loads almost instant.

I have tried priority and the sharp package but nothing changes.

Is this normal or am I missing something?

Comment: Probably just caching a fresh copy after deployment. Once deployed, I assume if you refresh it's loading quicker than the first time?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `sharp` for production for image optimization. The next/image component's default loader uses `squoosh` because it is quick to install and suitable for a development environment.

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sharp-missing-in-production
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/23637